# how I can use integrity api instead of safetyNet Api in phone login Fragment

Tags: android, api, kotlin, integrity, safetynet

how I can use Integrity Api instead of safetyNet Api in phone login Fragment.. I try to upload my App to Google play and my phone login fragment depend on SafetyNet Api which is Deprecated
and when Google play team warn me
I add this to my geadle to remove SaftyNet

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}
```

How I can sole this problem and any new

**my old code**

```
class PhoneLoginFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

private var _binding: FragmentPhoneLoginBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private val model by viewModels<PhoneLoginViewModel>()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentPhoneLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

    onBackClicked {
        if (model.loading.value!! || model.page.value!! == PhoneLoginPage.VERIFY) {
           // showCancelConfirmationDialog()
        } else goBack()
    }

    binding.phoneNumber.onTextChange { model.removePhoneNumberError() }
    binding.verificationCode.onTextChange { model.removeVerificationCodeError() }

    binding.phoneNumber.setOnDoneClick { sendCode() }
    binding.verificationCode.setOnDoneClick { model.verify(binding.verificationCode.value) }

    getResult<Boolean>(IS_CANCELED) {
        if (!it) return@getResult
        model.onLoginCanceled()
        //if user is in verification page, clear phone number field.
        binding.phoneNumber.setText("")
    }

    getResult<Boolean>(SEND_CODE) { if (it) sendCodeAgain() }

    observe(model.signedIn) { if (it) openActivity(MainActivity::class.java) }

    observe(model.loading) {
        binding.root.enableViews(!it)
        binding.loginProgress.isVisible = it
        binding.verificationProgress.isVisible = it
    }

    observe(model.error) {
        showSnackBar(it ?: return@observe) {
            when (model.page.value) {
                PhoneLoginPage.LOGIN -> sendCode()
                PhoneLoginPage.VERIFY -> model.verify(binding.verificationCode.value)
                else -> {}
            }
        }
        model.removeError()
    }

    observe(model.phoneNumberError) { binding.phoneNumberContainer.error = it }

    observe(model.verificationCodeError) { binding.verificationCodeContainer.error = it }

    observe(model.page) {
        val shownPage =
            if (binding.login.isVisible) PhoneLoginPage.LOGIN else PhoneLoginPage.VERIFY

        if (it == shownPage) return@observe

        when (it ?: return@observe) {
            PhoneLoginPage.LOGIN -> crossFade(binding.login, binding.verification) {
                openKeyboard(binding.phoneNumber)
            }
            PhoneLoginPage.VERIFY -> crossFade(binding.verification, binding.login) {
                openKeyboard(binding.verificationCode)
            }
        }
    }

    observe(model.phoneNumber) {
        val text = getString(R.string.code_sent_to_number, it ?: return@observe)
        binding.toVerifyNumber.text = text
    }

    binding.loginSubmit.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.verificationSubmit.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.sendAgain.setOnClickListener(this)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v?.id) {
        binding.loginSubmit.id -> sendCode()
        binding.verificationSubmit.id -> model.verify(binding.verificationCode.value)
        binding.sendAgain.id -> showSendAgainConfirmationDialog()
    }
}

private fun showCancelConfirmationDialog() {
    goTo(
        PhoneLoginFragmentDirections.actionGlobalConfirmationDialog(
             IS_CANCELED,
             getString(R.string.cancel_phone_login),
             null,
             getString(R.string.cancel),
             getString(R.string.dismiss)
        )
    )
}

private fun showSendAgainConfirmationDialog() {
    goTo(
        PhoneLoginFragmentDirections.actionGlobalConfirmationDialog(
             SEND_CODE,
             getString(R.string.send_code_again),
             null,
             getString(R.string.send),
             getString(R.string.cancel)
        )
    )
}



private fun sendCode() {
    val phoneNumber = binding.phoneNumber.value
    val numberWithCode = requireContext().addCountryCode(phoneNumber)
    model.onSendCode(numberWithCode) {
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(Firebase.auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(numberWithCode)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(requireActivity())
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }
}

private fun sendCodeAgain() {
    model.onSendCodeAgain {
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(Firebase.auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(model.phoneNumber.value!!)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(requireActivity())
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }
}

private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        model.onVerificationCompleted(credential)
    }

    override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
        model.onVerificationFailed(e)
    }

    override fun onCodeSent(
        verificationId: String,
        token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    ) {
        model.onCodeSent(verificationId)
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    _binding = null
}

companion object {
    private const val IS_CANCELED = "IS_CANCELED"
    private const val SEND_CODE = "SEND_CODE"
}
```

}

**Any help please**

Comment: have you found a solution here with play integrity API in the meantime?

Comment: How about now? Deprecating an API with no replacement is really cool.

Comment: @RaideR , I return to use SafetyNet

Comment: @Flonk ,I return to use SafetyNet..because I search alot without real Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really I don't find any suitable solution till Now,so I return to use **SafetyNet** with Phone Login and there no relation between **App Intergrity** and phone login

Comment: Yes you're right - Google does not support that use case in the moment. If you have the chance you are better off using SafetyNet.

see also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75603944/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-in-2023/75813278#75813278